# How do I get audio to auto switch between devices?

Tags: windows-8, audio, speakers, headphones, headset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing default playback device on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/515201/changing-default-playback-device-on-windows-8)

Whenever I'm watching something on Chrome or playing a game and decided to plug a headset in or unplug it and go to speakers, I have to close the program and open it again.

I just want it to auto switch because some programs do it but others don't and Chrome used to do it for me on Windows 7 but it doesn't on Windows 8. It gets really annoying and I was wondering if there was a setting anywhere for it?

Comment: Assuming you have an Intel motherboard with built-in RealTek sound, try installing the HD audio drivers from [RealTek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/). Those drivers provide one playback device, "Speakers", which switches automatically when you plug in a headphone jack.