# Change output device automatically when headset connected

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have a wireless Logitech headset that I use frequently and speakers connected to my computer. I'd like it if when I turn on the headset and it automatically connects to the PC, the sound output automatically changes to the headset and switches back when I disconnect it.

There's no option in Windows or the Logitech software that does this from what I can find.

I attempted doing this with the Windows Task Scheduler, but connecting doesn't seem to create any kind of event.

Is there some powershell script I could write to handle this or a better method?

I found [AudioDeviceCmdlets](https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets) which does some of what I'm looking for, but not exactly. I'm kind of new to powershell so I'm not certain how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not switching automatically, then connect your headset and open the Sound control panel. Find your headset in playback devices, then right click > Set as Default Device > OK. That specific configuration gets saved, and windows will switch back to it when you reconnect the headset.

Side note: With multiple audio devices, Windows remembers default devices according to a [timestamp](https://superuser.com/a/1482424/673426) representing to when they were marked as default. More recent = higher priority.

Some headsets get assigned as a "Default Communication Device" by default, which means they're **only** used for audio/video calls. It's in the same context menu as above, but is a separate "Default".

That said, individual applications like Zoom can choose to ignore the windows settings and use their own list instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I've set the headset as default and when I connect, Windows doesn't switch over to it as the audio output device. It might be important to note that the headphones aren't bluetooth or any other standard, but rather use a Logitech Lightspeed connector. Any thoughts?

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 I'm not familiar with those. Does the headset show as Disconnected in the sound control panel when it's off? When you turn it off, does windows automatically switch back to your speakers? Some USB headsets (usually with a base) need a driver update to tell windows when they disconnect, if they do at all. Maybe see if there's a newer driver or updated version of the logitech software?

Comment: No, it doesn't show as disconnected. No, it doesn't switch back to speakers when I disconnect the wireless headset. The logitech software is all up to date. Sounds like it just doesn't really support that Windows feature.

Comment: Yeah that does seem like strange behavior. There may be some advanced options in the g hub app, but I'm not familiar. There are some automation examples in the answers here: https://superuser.com/questions/437958/switch-playback-device-using-logitech-g-key , but I'm not sure how to trigger them if you're not getting device connect/disconnect events like a usb/bluetooth headset. Another alternative might be just unplugging the usb connector, but that's not ideal either